# How to change from "CHAPITRE" to "CHAPTER"

Tags: chapters, babel

I am writing a PhD thesis. Some parts of my thesis need to be in French, but the main language is English. I am using

```
\documentclass[english,letterpaper,12pt,oneside,final]{book}

\usepackage[french, english, USenglish]{babel}
```

Here is my problem:

`\chapter{...}` is generating CHAPITRE, which I do not want and it is happening because of the "french" option. But I want CHAPTER as the heading instead of CHAPITRE.

Comment: Have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20987/changing-babel-package-inside-a-single-chapter, it probably solves your requirements.

Comment: remove the english option in the documentclass.

Answer (score 27):

Let's see what happens.

1. You have `english` as a global option;
2. You repeat it in the options to `babel`.
3. When `babel` is loaded, the `english` global option is passed first, then `french`; when it comes to `english`, it does nothing, because the relevant `.ldf` file has already been loaded; the same holds for `USenglish`.

However, `babel` sets as main language the one specified in the last loaded language definition file, which in this case is `french.ldf`.

Solution: don't specify `english` in the global options, so

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt,oneside,final]{book}
```

Alternatively, if you really need the global option, call `babel` as

```
\usepackage[french,main=english]{babel}
```