# Special letters without changing Latex objects names

Tags: fonts

I am preparing a document in English.

In the preamble I have (amongst other things):

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}
```

There are two Icelandic words in the document containing the letters ð and Þ (uppercase þ).

So I change the preamble to my usual

```
\usepackage[icelandic]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

But that changes the name of all the in-built beauties such as my `\tableofcontents`.

Is there an *easy* way around this perhaps by introducing a new language for only one paragraph?

Comment: The babel package offers commands for switching the language inside the document. See e.g. http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/20991 .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main language in `babel` is the last specified language:

```
\usepackage[icelandic, english]{babel}
```

But I would not use `icelandic` for just two words. The symbols can be used as macros or direct, depending on the loaded input encoding (package `inputenc`). Thorn is not available in font encoding `OT1`, therefore font encoding `T1` is used:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}
Two Icelandic words with \dh\ and \TH.
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: This seems to work but without `\uspackage{lmodern}` which seems to conflict with `\usepackage{boldline}`... Also can't remember why I was using `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` instead of `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`. Will hope the best.

Comment: @snoram you shouldn't use `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` *instead* of `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` but very likely in *addition*. The two serve different purposes. (IIRC there is a question somewhere on tex.sx about that matter)

Comment: @clemens [fontenc vs inputenc](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44694/)

Comment: @clemens What can I say? You saved my life!

Answer (score 2):

The T1 encoding supports the letters:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{document}

We can use Icelandic letters with no
problem: Ð ð Þ þ

\end{document}
```

[image]

Beware that not all fonts support the letters, even in T1 encoding, so  check carefully if you use a different font.

Comment: @snoram I tried `ê` and have no problem

Comment: @snoram Is your document saved in UTF-8 encoding?