# Change language to Spanish in template

Tags: babel

https://www.overleaf.com/read/rmzywchdhqbs

This is the link to the template. More specific I want to change the language using the package babel, but is not working well.

Comment: Do you have to use `babel`? Have you tried `polyglossia`?

Comment: Hard to tell exactly what your issue is, but see if this link helps: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/20991/121944

Comment: @AML `polyglossia` is only usable with XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX but the template loads `fontenc` with the T1 encoding so this will not work. Furthermore, since Javier Bezos, the maintainer of `babel` is Spanish, support for Spanish is most certainly more mature in `babel`.

Comment: What do you mean by “not working well”?

Comment: @AlanMunn Well, as far as `babel` is concerned, I'm trying to be language agnostic. But on the other hand, I'm the maintainer of `babel-spanish`, too. Anyway, I'd say support for LGC languages is in general better in `babel` than in `polyglossia` (even for XeTeX and LuaTeX), thanks to the contributed language styles.

Comment: @JavierBezos That's all I meant. :) But in this particular case, `polyglossia` isn't an option anyway.

Comment: Thanks to all, for answer. I am new in LaTeX. 

I want only one thing in mi LaTeX file. For Example I need to change the label of one picture, like Figure to Figura or Capter to Capitulo, Index to Indice. etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to a clash between the `babel-spanish` option and the `nag` package. To get around this, you can either load `spanish` with some modifiers:

```
\usepackage[english,spanish.notilde.lcroman,shorthands=off]{babel}
```

OR alternatively, comment out the `\RequirePackage[l2tabu]{nag}` on the first line. (Probably inadvisable to do so...)

Comment: I mean that the problem with this templete form Overleaf, is because in the main .tex, there are two package that include the leguage spanish. for example in line 3, I have: `\RequirePackage[l2tabu]{nag}` and in the 167 `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} ` and the last in line 183 `\usepackage[spanish,english]{babel}`

Comment: And my response fixes this; I've updated my response to make this clearer. Your project now compiles fine after I used the `spanish.notilde.lcroman` option.

Comment: Thank you very much, Lian, these commands were very useful and solved the problem.