# Caslon font looks completely different in the English and Russian versions of the same document

Tags: fonts, russian

I am working with a writer, whose requirement is to typeset a book in Latex, in Caslon font. In the English version everything is hunky-dory:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{memoir}
\usepackage{librecaslon}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

But there is also a requirement to translate and typeset the text into Russian, and here there is a problem. The font is not even close to Caslon, and everything shifts even before the translation:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{memoir}
\usepackage{librecaslon}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[main=russian]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

I am using TexLive 2018 on a Fedora 26 machine. Can anyone please explain, how both versions can be rendered in the exact same font?

Comment: In LaTeX, this font is not supported in Russian language. That is the reason, and you can only use a different font, or provide a Russian version for the font. Read more [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/114598/156344).

Comment: libre caslon doesn't have cyrilic glyphs. You will need another font.

Comment: You should tell Babel that you want to use both English and Russian and then indicate for different text fragments which language it is, i.e., `\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}` and then `\begin{otherlanguage}{english}\lipsum[1]\end{otherlanguage}` (see, e.g., https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20987/changing-babel-package-inside-a-single-chapter).