# Using old German language for part in new German (ngerman) document

Tags: babel, german

I have seen [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20987/98645) and so on, but I seem to get compilation errors when trying to use `foreigndisplayquote`, which is basically just `otherlanguage` from babel and `displayquote` from `csquotes`.

The same error of course happens when I use that inline or so via `\foreignlanguage{german}{daß}`.

My document is in ngerman, i.e. "new" German language, but I'd like to quote a part in german, i.e. the old version, because well… that text is just so old. [See here for the difference.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/67549/98645)

When I change that to another language I have loaded, e.g. `english` it works.

But the example below in my case throws an error like this one:

> Your command will be ignored, type to proceed ! Package babel Error: You haven't defined the language en yet. See the babel package documentation for explanation. Type H for immediate help.

However, I did actually install the babel `german` language package (also tested online on overleaf etc.) and also added the language to babel, as you can see.

Simplified document:

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
% !TeX encoding = UTF-8
% !TeX spellcheck = de_DE
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,titlepage,numbers=noenddot,oneside]{scrbook}
\KOMAoption{listof}{totocnumbered, leveldown}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc}

\usepackage[norsk, english, german, ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[norsk, english, german, ngerman]{isodate}
\usepackage{lmodern} % font
\usepackage[german=quotes]{csquotes} % deutsche Anführunsgzeichen mit \enquote

\begin{document}
    \begin{foreigndisplayquote}[german]
        Daß ist ein alter Text.
    \end{foreigndisplayquote}
\end{document}
```

TexLive 2019

Comment: You should use neither `inputenc` nor `luainputenc`: both do essentially nothing in your situation.

Comment: @user187802 Off-topic, but when I don't use these two (at least luainputenc), `inputenc` may be omit table, writing many characters like `…` (one character) does not work, i.e. they are not printed in the PDF then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The language is not an optional argument!

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,titlepage,numbers=noenddot,oneside]{scrbook}
\KOMAoption{listof}{totocnumbered, leveldown}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[norsk, english, german, main=ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[norsk, english, german, ngerman]{isodate}
\usepackage[autostyle,german=quotes]{csquotes} % deutsche Anführunsgzeichen mit \enquote

\begin{document}

\begin{foreigndisplayquote}{german}
        Daß ist ein alter Text.
\end{foreigndisplayquote}

\end{document}
```

And, by the way: Do not use luainputenc. UTF8 is for years the default!