# Changing babel package inside the same document

Tags: babel, characters, thesis, french, english

I am currently writing my Ph.D. thesis in French and English. Following the procedure that I found here [Changing babel package inside a single chapter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20987/changing-babel-package-inside-a-single-chapter), I have divided the document into two parts, one for the French one and one for the English one. It seemed to work fine when uploading the first French chapter. However, starting from the second Chapter LateX goes crazy looking like this:

[image]

I am using the following packages:

```
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage[french,english]{babel}
```

while the code concerning the French part looks like this:

```
\begin{otherlanguage}{french}
     \input{Chapter1_FR/Chapter1_FR}
     \input{Chapter2_FR/Chapter2_FR}
\end{otherlanguage}
```

I have tried to run the code with Chapter 2 only but it still gives the same output. What do you think could be the problem and how can I solve it?
Thank you a lot in advance!

P.S. at the moment there are no issues concerning the switch to English.

Comment: Quite likely, your input files are UTF-8 coded, not Latin-1. Use the same encoding for all files, UTF-8 is recommended.

Comment: The reason why I was using Latin1 was that I was getting as error: ! Package inputenc Error: Invalid UTF-8 byte sequence. 
However, running with UTF-8 solves the issue with Chapter 2. Is there a way to run both Chapters without facing errors?

Comment: That's why using the same encoding for all files helps. Check that all of them are saved as UTF-8. How to do it depends on the editor or front-end you use.

Comment: Ok I have found out one of the file is not saved as UTF-8, how can I convert it into this format?

Comment: Which editor or front-end do you use?